# issue in flink upgrade from 1.8.2 to 1.10.3

Tags: apache-flink

I am trying to upgrade Flink from 1.8.2 to 1.10.3. 1.8.2 is working fine with configuration

```
jobmanager.heap.mb: ${jobManagerHeapSize}
taskmanager.heap.mb: ${jobManagerHeapSize}
taskmanager.memory.preallocate: false
```

modified to

```
jobmanager.heap.mb: ${jobManagerHeapSize}
taskmanager.memory.process.size: 1024
```

Then I am getting the following error

```
Caused by: org.apache.flink.configuration.IllegalConfigurationException: The required configuration option Key: 'taskmanager.cpu.cores' , default: null (fallback keys: []) is not set
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskExecutorResourceUtils.checkConfigOptionIsSet(TaskExecutorResourceUtils.java:90)
```

I tried adding cores then getting error `to provide taskmanager.memory.task.heap.size`  and then `taskmanager.memory.managed.size`. As per the [docs](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/deployment/memory/mem_setup/), just `taskmanager.memory.process.size` is enough and other memory options will be calculated. what is the issue here.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the problem is that `1024` bytes is not enough memory for the task manager. You probably intended to configure `1024m`, but that might not be enough either -- the default configuration specifies `1728m`.